# Keep background image in place with text-indent

Tags: html, css

I have the following html inside a `<div>`:

```
<span class="footer-icons">
    <a href="#;" class="facebook" title="Facebook">Facebook</a>
    <a href="#;" class="twitter" title="Twitter">Twitter</a>
</span>
```

And my CSS:

```
#footer .footer-icons {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#footer .footer-icons {
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
#footer .footer-icons .facebook {
    background: url("../images/new/footer-icons.png");
}
```

The problem with this is that the `text-indent` is causing the background-image to move also. How would I make it such that I can 'escape the text' (for example, using text-indent: -9999px) and keep the background image in place?

Comment: Have you tried `background-position: 0 0` or `background-position: top left`? Or whatever particular position you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/qdFNM/5/  **(Updated)**

Add display:inline-block & give a width & height to that div same as image.

**CSS**

```
.footer-icons {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.footer-icons {
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
.footer-icons .facebook {
    background: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19982181/fab/fb.jpg") no-repeat left top ;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.footer-icons .twitter {
    background: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19982181/fab/tw.jpg") no-repeat left top ;
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px; height:20px;
}
```

Comment: Right, because the negative `text-indent` moves the element itself. Now, what if `display: block` isn't going to work for the OP?

Comment: use display:inline-block. And its not good to use my dropbox image in your fiddle.

Comment: @user1383058 then you have to submit your complete code of footer using jsfiddle.net so i can debug.

Comment: @SVS - one thing I'm running into is `display:block` will work, but when I try `display:inline-block` (which I need), it disappears. Would you know how to fix that?

Comment: Lucky guess. I use my own Gravatar with goo.gl short url. Makes for some laughs at times.

Comment: Just an observation, but you're copying and duplicating your css properties; why not subsume the commonalities to another statement for the `.footer-icons a` and leave the `.footer-icons .twitter` and `.facebook` one's only to `background-image: url(...)`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish User wants the answer which is important, Optimization is secondary for now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, using `<i>`, which is what [Twitter's Bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons) suggests for their icons:

**NOTE** - This is link-friendly. Of course, an `A` tag could be used instead of `i`. But this also works:

```
<div id="footer">
    <span class="footer-icons">
        <a href="#;" class="facebook" title="Facebook">
            <i class="facebook"></i>Facebook
        </a>
        <a href="#;" class="twitter" title="Twitter">
            <i class="twitter"></i>Twitter
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

On the `margin-right`, I moved it due to jsFiddle's `Result` label overlay getting in the way.

```
#footer .footer-icons {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.footer-icons a {
    font-size: 0;
}
.footer-icons i {
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 0 0 0 35px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.footer-icons i.facebook {
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/QrKCc);
}
.footer-icons i.twitter {
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/QrKCc);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/qdFNM/10/

---

***Original Answer***

```
<div id="footer">
    <span class="footer-icons">
        <i class="facebook"></i>
        <a href="#;" class="facebook" title="Facebook">Facebook</a>
        <i class="twitter"></i>
        <a href="#;" class="twitter" title="Twitter">Twitter</a>
    </span>
</div>

#footer .footer-icons {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.footer-icons a {
    display: none;
}
.footer-icons i {
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 0 0 0 35px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.footer-icons i.facebook {
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/QrKCc);
}
.footer-icons i.twitter {
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/QrKCc);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/qdFNM/4/